# X11 Forwarding from Windows to Linux

Tags: x11, windows

Everybody knows how to run graphical programs remotely from Linux to Windows (ssh -X).
And now, if I want the reverse...
I'd want to display graphical programs executed on a windows machine remotely on a linux host(debian)?
Like rdesktop but with resizing feature!

Do you think this is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried VNC? Since Win32 apps do not use X (they use GDI or something like that instead) you can't simply "forward" them to Linux. I think RDP is the best solution here, but VNC could also be used.

Comment: [Yes I think that is possible.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/should-we-try-and-educate-our-users-not-to-ask-does-anyone-or-who-can)

Comment: It's definately possible. Every day at work I use the Citrix solution for that.

Comment: @albator_123, remember that in X the server provides the display, keyboard and  mouse to the clients which are the applications.

Comment: Have a look at [xpra](https://xpra.org/). It works on Linux, Mac and Windows. It can forward single applications from Linux, but I'm not sure about the other systems. (Maybe Win and Mac can only be forwarded as whole desktop like with VNC. Just try it out).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for Windows software.

Comment: Many thanks for your remplies. After some times, my best solution is VDI... The best solution for my context

Answer (score -1):

Yes but . . .

Firstly it is just as easy for any windows application to show a window on an X server as any linux application. For example the cygwin distribution does this all the time. Unfortunately most windows applications are not linked against xlib or the like and just show using the windows apis. Disappointing, I know, but there is hope!

For proper X11 display of winapi programs one method that was on my todo list for years without my getting to it before deciding windows was not worth my time was to port wine to windows. I know what you are thinking why would you need wine on windows because wine provides windows` api to systems that don't have it and windows already has windows' api, but it is genius I tell you! When running windows programs on linux wine intercepts the graphics api calls and maps them to X11 requests, and if you override the libraries on windows you can do the same thing. I don't know if anyone has done this but it should work.

If wine on windows seems like too much work rdesktop hints about a single window export that I have never got working and there are or were some hints about doing the same with vnc (It was mentioned in the w95 days). Also both easily do full screen in a window and there are other commercial applications that can do the same.

Regardless of which you use forwarding over ssh is no harder than it would be on a linux box (other than running a ssh server on windows which is annoying). Me? I would give windows a much as a heave as I can. My choices are replace, port, wine, or vm in that order.